# Ошибка при миграции C# EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Такая вот ошибка:
[image: Ошибка]

Вот код всех моделей:

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Surname { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public List<ClientSeasonTicket> ClientSeasonTickets { get; set; }
    public List<ClientTraining> ClientTrainings { get; set; }
}
public class ClientSeasonTicket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int VisitsNumber { get; set; }
    public SeasonTicket SeasonTicket { get; set; }
    public int SeasonTicketId { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public Coach Coach { get; set; }
    public int? CoachId { get; set; }
    public Section Section { get; set; }
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public Gym Gym { get; set; }
    public int GymId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public int? GroupId { get; set; }
    public List<ClientTraining> ClientTrainings { get; set; }
}
public class ClientTraining
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Training Training { get; set; }
    public int TrainingId { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public ClientSeasonTicket ClientSeasonTicket { get; set; }
    public int ClientSeasonTicketId { get; set; }
    public TrainingVisiting Visiting { get; set; } = TrainingVisiting.NotAttend;

}
public class Coach
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Surname { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int PassportSeries { get; set; }
    public int PassportNumber { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Section Section { get; set; }
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public List<ClientSeasonTicket> ClientSeasonTickets { get; set; }
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public List<Training> Trainings { get; set; }
    public List<CoachContact> CoachContacts { get; set; }
}
public class CoachContact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Link { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Coach Coach { get; set; }
    public int CoachId { get; set; }
}
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Coach Coach { get; set; }
    public int CoachId { get; set; }
    public Section Section { get; set; }
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public List<Training> Trainings { get; set; }
    public List<ClientSeasonTicket> ClientSeasonTickets { get; set; }
}
public class Gym
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public double Area { get; set; }
    public List<Section> Sections { get; set; }
    public List<Training> Trainings { get; set; }
    public List<ClientSeasonTicket> ClientSeasonTickets { get; set; }
}
public class SeasonTicket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public SeasonTicketType Type { get; set; } = SeasonTicketType.OneTime;
    public int? AvailableVisits { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public List<ClientSeasonTicket> ClientSeasonTickets { get; set; }
}
public class Section
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public List<Gym> Gyms { get; set; }
    public List<Coach> Coaches { get; set; }
    public List<ClientSeasonTicket> ClientSeasonTickets { get; set; }
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public List<Training> Trainings { get; set; }
}
public class Training
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime Duration { get; set; }
    public string? Notes { get; set; }
    public Gym Gym { get; set; }
    public int GymId { get; set; }
    public Coach Coach { get; set; }
    public int? CoachId { get; set; }
    public Section Section { get; set; }
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public int? GroupId { get; set; }
    public List<ClientTraining> ClientTrainings { get; set; }
}
```

Я подозреваю что это из за того, что в **Groups** есть внешний ключ из таблицы **Sections**, и так же есть внешний ключ из таблицы **Coaches**, которая в свою очередь так же имеет связь с таблицей **Sections**. А затем еще и группа связана с таблицей **ClientSeasonTickets**, которая так же связана с **Coaches** и с **Sections**. Может кто-нибудь объяснить в чем именно причина, чтобы я понял свою ошибку. И так же подскажите, как исправить эту пожалуйста. EntityFramework последней версии использую, СУБД - MsSQL.

Comment: Единственно, что могу посоветовать, почитать документацию: [Cascade Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete). Много и сложно, но куда деваться.

Comment: Укажите точную версию EF. А также используемую СУБД, на всякий случай. Метки asp.net можно удалить, т. к. они не относятся к сути вопроса.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо за помощь, попробую разобраться!

Comment: _EntityFramework последней версии использую_ - укажите **точную** версию, цифрами!

Comment: _СУБД - MsSQL_ - нет такой СУБД, в природе не существует. Есть Sql Server.